# Backbone.js without using Require.js- How to kick off the app with the main.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm new to backbone and im trying to kick start my application using the structure backbone follows:

├── router.js

|___app.js

│── main.js

this is my main.js with require.js added to the project:

```
 'use strict';

 require.config({
   baseUrl: '../',

    paths: {
      jquery: 'libs/jquery-1.10.2',
      underscore: 'libs/underscore',
      backbone: 'libs/backbone',
      text: 'libs/require/text',

      bootstrap: 'libs/bootstrap',
      mustache:  'libs/mustache'
  },
 require([
   'app'
  ], function (App) {
      console.log('prepare to start app');
      App.initialize();
});
```

Now i want to use backbone without using require js. How can i write my main.js then? I'm assuming in that case, i wouldn't be able to write `require.config` as it would need the require.js. any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use `require`, you'll have to embed all your scripts in html using `<script>` tag. A sample would look like this :

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src='jquery.js'></script>
  <script src='underscore.js'></script>
  <script src='backbone.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='view'></div>
  <script src='router.js'></script>
  <script>
    router.start();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```